# My form loops its submit depending on how many times I've submitted it even if there is no looping statement - js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, modal-dialog

We are making a JavaScript banking app and I have a code block that manages a form for a deposit transaction. As with normal banking apps, you're expected to use the deposit transaction multiple times and that's what we're supposed to design it to do. The deposit form is within a modal and the problem is for some reason, it loops its submission depending on how many times I've called to submit. For example, if I deposit 100 the first time, it will only deposit 100. But if I open the modal and deposit 100 again, it will call the function twice and deposit 200. The same thing happens on the third (100 x 3), and so on and so forth. Below is my code block for the event listener.

```
////////// DEPOSIT MODAL
if(depositModal) { // Checks for existence of depositModal (true in index.html, false in newuser.html)
    depositBts.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(activeUser == undefined) { // Checks activeUser
            alert("Please enter a valid account number before trying a transaction!")
        } else {
            depositModal.classList.add('openDepositModal') // Opens deposit modal on click of deposit button
            let depositForm = document.getElementById('depositForm');

            depositForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
                let depositAmountInput = document.getElementById('depositAmountInput').value;
                activeUser.balance = parseInt(activeUser.balance) + parseInt(depositAmountInput);
                currentBalance.innerHTML = "PHP " + activeUser.balance.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
                console.log(activeUser)
                localStorage.setItem(activeUserKey, JSON.stringify(activeUser));
                alert(`Successfuly deposited PHP ${depositAmountInput}`);
                // depositForm.reset();
                depositModal.classList.remove('openDepositModal');
                e.preventDefault();
                })
        }
    }
)};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there any looping statement in your codeblock ?

Comment: @MartneyAcha None in this code block, there's a looping statement in the same script but it shouldn't affect this code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time the value of `depositModal` changes, you add a new event listener on the `depositBtn` button.

I believe that clicking the button toggles your modal. The number of event listeners on the button depends on the times you toggled the modal.

You should add the event listener only once. On a place independent of the logic that handles the `modal`. Moving it outside the `if` statement should be enough..`

Comment: Had to find this out the hard way yesterday after hours of tinkering! But thank you so much, this was exactly what I did, placing the submit event listener on a separate code block, and that did the trick.